# Delete query update records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I used the following code to **delete** some records, but surprisingly it just **updates** the [`Date`] field (DataType Date )in my `History` table.

I run the query independently on DB and it works correctly, but when I run it in the code it just update the [Date] field to `'2635-11-14'`.

Any idea will be welcomed.

```
internal void DeleteDate(DateTime day)
{
      OpenConnection();
      query.Parameters.Clear();
          
      command = @"delete [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[History]  where [Date]=@day";
      query.CommandText = command;
      query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day);
      query.ExecuteNonQuery();

      CloseConnection();
}
```

**Update:**

I used this query and it works right. I belive my problem is still with  `@day`

```
delete [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[History]
```

Comment: Are you sure? Did you debug your code? I don't see any `UPDATE` command in your code. Maybe problem could be somewhere else? What `OpenConnection` and `CloseConnection` methods do?

Comment: @popovitsj i just debug it for several times and took a look at open and close connection methods.........., but your comment was not helpful

Comment: this code sample isn't substantial enough for anyone to assist you with this, as the limited code sample seems fine. I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Probably, The INSTEAD OF DELETE TRIGGER is in your database.

Comment: @MikkaRin: He wrote, that running the query against the DB and that works correctly, so it is not an INSTEAD OF trigger.

Comment: @Kam: in case of this is an MS SQL Server, and you have client tools, please monitor the SQL sent to your DB with SQL Server profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this, and also check your stored procedure in backend DB.

```
command=new sqlcommand("name of your stored procedure in DB",connection);

command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Command.CommandText="name of your stored procedure in DB";

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day);

Coomand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to assign your command with the following syntax;

```
command = "delete from [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[History]  where [Date]=@day";
```